# Spatial Index not being used

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb, spatial

I have a spatial index on GEO_LOCATION column, but when I do EXPLAIN it doesn't show that the index is being used. Can anyone tell why?

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT AsText(GEO_LOCATION) 
FROM PERSON 
WHERE ST_Distance(POINT(-94.0724223,38.0234332), GEO_LOCATION) <= 10
```

id: 1
select type: SIMPLE
table: PERSON
type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
key: NULL
key_len: NULL
ref: NULL
rows: 612602
Extra: Using where

This is my environment:
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.1.8-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version: 10
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.14
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation
PHP version: 5.6.14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately [`ST_Distance() < threshold`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-distance) isn't a [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) search criterion.  To satisfy this query, MySQL must compute the function's value for every row in the table, and then compare it to the threshold. So it has to do a full table scan (or maybe a full index scan).

To exploit an index to speed up this query, you're going to need a bounding-box criterion.  The query is a lot more elaborate but also a lot faster. Assuming your x/y points in your geometry represent latitude/longitude in degrees, that query might look like this:

```
   set @latpoint = 38.0234332;
   set @lngpoint = -94.0724223;
   set @r = 10.0;    /* ten mile radius */
   set @units=69.0;    /* 69 statute miles per degree */
   SELECT AsText(geo) 
     FROM markers
      WHERE MbrContains(GeomFromText( 
       CONCAT('LINESTRING(', @latpoint-(@r/@units),' ',
                             @lngpoint-(@r /(@units* COS(RADIANS(@latpoint)))), 
                          ',', 
                             @latpoint+(@r/@units) ,' ', 
                             @lngpoint+(@r /(@units * COS(RADIANS(@latpoint)))),
                           ')')),
                    geo)
```

How does this work?  For one thing, the [MbrContains(bound,item)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-mysql-specific.html) function *is* [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). For another thing, the big ugly concat item yields a diagonal line from the southwest to the northeast corner of the bounding rectangle. Using your data point and ten mile radius it looks like this.

```
LINESTRING(37.8785 -94.2564,38.1684 -93.8884)
```

When you use the `GeomFromText()` rendering of that diagonal line in the first argument to `MbrContains()` it serves as a bounding rectangle.  `MbrContains()` can then exploit the nifty quadtree geometry index.

Thirdly, `ST_Distance()`, in MySQL, doesn't handle great circle latitude and longitude computations. ([PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) has a more comprehensive [GIS extension](http://postgis.net/).) MySQL's is as dumb as a flapjack in flatland. It assumes your points in your geometric objects are represented in planar geometry. So `ST_Distance() < 10.0` with lng/lat points does something strange.

There's one flaw in the results this query generates; it returns all the points in the bounding box, not just within the specified radius. That's solvable with a separate distance computation. I've written all this up [in some detail here](http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/using-mysqls-geospatial-extension-location-finder/).

*Note*: For GPS-resolution latitude and longitude, 32-bit `FLOAT` data has sufficient precision. `DOUBLE` is what MySQL's geo extension uses. When you're working in degrees, more than five places after the decimal point is beyond the precision of GPS. `DECIMAL()` is not an ideal datatype for lat/lng coordinates.

Comment: Wow. What a trove of information! Going to look at this closer later today. Totally makes sense. Thank you Ollie! I searched forever trying to find those nuggets of information.

Comment: Had to do a little test before I ran off to my daughter's basketball game this morning (will dive in more this evening). So, it doesn't return any matches even if I put known lat/lng with/in 10 miles. I've tried it with several known points and still nothing.

Comment: If the points in your table use a SRID (spatial reference identifier), make sure you add the same SRID as the second (optional) argument of the GeomFromText() function: `GeomFromText('...', 4326)` for example.

Comment: When using a SRID of 4326 (or similar I would guess), spatial data is defined as X=lon and Y=lat, so one would need to use `@latpoint` instead of `@lngpoint`, and vice-versa, in the above code.

Comment: The calculation of the bounding coordinates above is not quite accurate: http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates#LongitudeIncorrect

Comment: Also, when using an SRID, it is necessary to explicitly wrap coordinates, such as when longitude is near +/-180. MySQL reports an error if the coordinates are not strictly +/-90, +/-180.