# Why doesn't mysql utilise this spatial index?

Tags: mysql, key, spatial

MySQL/InnoDB+MyISAM 5.7.20...

Given:

```
mysql> desc city;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | mediumint(9) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name      | char(30)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| geo       | geometry     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
mysql> show index from city;
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| city  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |      798000 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| city  |          1 | geo      |            1 | geo         | A         |      882478 |       32 | NULL   |      | SPATIAL    |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Yet...

```
mysql> explain select distinct name from city where st_distance_sphere(@p, geo) < 5000;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | city  | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 882478 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
```

So it's clear (from the type = ALL) that the spatial index isn't being used. Can somebody explain to me why not? It's the same with both InnoDB and MyISAM storage engines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spatial Index not being usedfirefox prevent adblock update to new version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35093608/3404097) PS [mcve] please.

Comment: You are correct philipxy. Your referenced issue does indeed explain the cause of - and the solution to - the problem. Thanks

Comment: I merely googled 'st_distance_sphere mySql spatial index not used null'. I can only infer that you didn't--why not? (Google my comments about googling questions.) Unfortunately a large portion of SO questions shouldn't have been posted, just googled.  (I added 'null' because you don't have any PKs--unusual.) I expect there are many more helpful spatial querying hits/hints waiting for you there. Good luck.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.

Comment: Wouldn't _most_ of the rows be within `5000`?  See whether it uses the index when you use `5`.

Answer (score 0):

As per [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-spatial-indexes.html).
You have to use function such as MBRContains() or MBRWithin() in the WHERE clause.